# How to make a bubble chart with GGally::ggpairs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart, ggally

I would like to create a bubble chart matrix using `GGally::ggpairs`.

Defining the point/bubble size in `ggplot2` is easy using the `size` argument:

```
library("ggplot2")
data(mtcars)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point(aes(size = qsec))
```

However, with `GGally::ggpairs` this does not work.
The following code produces this:

```
library("GGally")
ggpairs(mtcars[ ,c("mpg", "wt", "disp")], 
        size=mtcars$qsec)
```

[image: points obviously not varying in size=qsec]

And the following code does not even produce a plot

```
ggpairs(mtcars[ ,c("mpg", "wt", "disp")], 
        size="qsec")
> error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'qsec' not found
```

***Any ideas how to fix this?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the last error because `qsec` is not present in the subset `c("mpg", "wt", "disp")`.

```
ggpairs(mtcars[ ,c("mpg", "wt", "disp", "qsec")], columns = 1:3, size = "qsec")
```

[image]